# Exclude Current Entry

Tags: entries

How can I exclude the current entry when I've structured my syntax like this?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section:        'blog',
  order:          'postDate',
  limit:          5,
}) %}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section:        'blog',
  order:          'postDate',
  limit:          5,
  id:             'not ' ~ entry.id
}) %}
```

or

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section:        'blog',
  order:          'postDate',
  limit:          5,
}).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but then I get the error: "Variable "entry" does not exist".

Comment: What is the *current entry* that you are trying to exclude?

Comment: Ah, I understand. I'm editing the wrong template :(